# Why three.js pointcloud is not same rendering between mac and windows (Intel HD graphics 4000)?

Tags: three.js, point-clouds

I'm developing Huge PointCloud Viewer(over 10millions) using Three.js.
But, I got a strange result - not same rendering between mac and windows.

below figure is on Mac
[On Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFSzL.png), and next figure[On windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhlWZ.png) on Windows(7).

both uses Intel HD graphics 4000.
What's happens in Chrome Browser?

Addtionally informations: same situation are iPhoneSE, iPhoneX, iPad4, MacBook, MacBookAir, and MacBookPro. those machines display very sparsed point cloud(intel HD graphics series commonly)

But, only iMac(2017) displays Huge point cloud, successfully. It uses Radeon pro 555, not intel GPU.

I want to any message about info or/and err, but no error in "chrome_debug.log"

=== P.S. === below my code

```
if(data.point.position.length>0){
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.addAttribute('position', new  THREE.BufferAttribute(data.point.position, 3));
    geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(data.point.color, 3));
    var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        size:0.8,
        sizeAttenuation : true,
    });
}
```

=== P.P.S. ===
For all

Try and Error, before I may find resolving it.
When pointMaterial.sizeAttenuation = false, FAR perspective view on Mac like on Windows. However, NEAR perspective view become sparse point cloud.
But if NEAR perspective, creating with pointMaterial.sizeAttenuation = true, I got better than before result.

Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: From the looks of it, it might be only the first 64k points rendering in the problematic case. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @H.Gatz You need to show your code, otherwise we are guessing... Try adding `renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );` if you are not doing so already. The renderer will properly size the pixels for you.

Comment: Thank Mr.WestLangley for your suggestion. I didn't know it for Retina Display.
Soon, updating my code and test, but that result seems same for FAR perspective view. However, NEAR perspective view was changed exactly.

Answer (score 0):

On both the working and the failing configuration, visit to http://webglreport.com/?v=1 and check the value of the *OES_element_index_uint* extension. My assumption is that this extension not supported on the failing machine/OS combination (driver support missing on MacOS).

This extension is required by three.js to render more than 64k vertices from a single BufferGeometry. On machines that *don't* support this extension, you'll need to split up your geometry.

Comment: thanks Mr.Paul
I visited http://webglreport.com/?v=1, now.

I got extension "OES_element_index_uint" on MacBooKAir/Chrome and Firefox. 
But sparse cloud displayed, failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pixel density on Mac devices. Mac devices often have a pixel ratio of 2 or higher on retina displays. When you declare [pointsMaterial.size](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial.size), you're telling it how big each point is in pixels, so make sure you're taking `window.devicePixelRatio` into account when assigning their pixel size. Something like

```
pointsMaterial.size = mySize * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome users, disabling "Use hardware acceleration when available" could solve the sparse point cloud problem, but the fps may be very low.
I didn't dig into the further reason, if someone finds it, Pls let me know~

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).